# Compare response of http backends on live traffic

Tags: http, proxy, continuous-integration, staging

I'd like to compare the response to live customer requests from production with staging servers. The only thing I can think of is a minimal node.js application doing the proxing, but I would feel much more comfortable with using an existing solution.

The comparison can the done offline (if request and both responses are recorded somewhere), but the multiplexing has to be done on live traffic, so JMeter is not a solution.

Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Can you give more details? What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried using an nginx als frontend, and node.js in the middle and two apache as backend. The node.js application stores the request while forwarding it to staging and production. While both responses will be retained, only the production's gets forwarded to the client. But the setup is fragil since it depends on custom software on a critical path, which I try to avoid